# Share content to Messenger or Line or other like Facebook or Tweeter

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-messenger, messenger

Hi I am new to develop application in android.
I saw other apps, they use share to friends with Messenger, or Facebook..
for instant, I share it to Messenger, then in the content should show some texts and the link of app!!
How can I do that? anyone please help!!!
I have tried the answer in this site to share, but it works only with SMS and Gmail, but if I share to Messenger, it shows nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for sharing drawable image with link and text.

**Follow this steps**

**Step 1 :-** Take one button in your `layout.xml` for sharing your content.

**Step 2 :-** set `onClickListner` for this button in your `Activity.java`.

**Step 3 :-** Put this code to your `Activity.java` file Button `setOnClickListner`.

```
String myText = "share text though this string";
            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.icon_256);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String extraText = myText + "\n\nhttps://www.google.co.in";
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,extraText);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.fromFile(f));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! but I still wonder if I possibly create Image from my app to the folder on Storage of the Phone, then share it by fetch the uri of it. how can i do that?